# Get EditText value in AsyncTask inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a fragment with EditText fields for the user's address. I am trying to send them to my webserver through AsyncTask but have not figured out how to get the values. It works fine without fragments.  I tried to remove all unnecessary code.  Thanks.

```
public class FragmentProfileMain extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    EditText email2, email3, mail1, mail2, cityET, stateET, zipET;

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment_main, container,
            false);

    email1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileEmail1);
    email2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.profileEmail2);
    email3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.profileEmail3);
    mail1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.profileAddress1);
    mail2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.profileAddress2);
    cityET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.profileCity);
    stateET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.profileState);
    zipET = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.profileZip);

return view;
}

class saveInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            String secondemail = ((EditText) this.email2).getText().toString();
            String thirdemail = ((EditText) this.email3).getText().toString();
            String secaddress = ((EditText) this.mail1).getText().toString();
            String secaddresstwo = ((EditText) this.mail2).getText().toString();
            String secCity = ((EditText) this.cityET).getText().toString();
            String secState = ((EditText) this.stateET).getText().toString();
            String secZip = ((EditText) this.zipET).getText().toString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors or just no values? Have you considered creating a constructor for your `saveInfo` class and passing in the `EditText` references you created in the `onCreateView` of your fragment? Then you would have localised variables in the `saveInfo` class.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I get an error underlining email2, email3, etc in my section String secondemail = ((EditText) this.email2).getText().toString();  Hovering the error my choice is to Create field 'email2' in type saveInfo. Adding the field private EditText email2; in my class saveInfo doesn't help. It doesn't reference the EditText in the fragment.

Comment: OK. You are referencing `this.email2`, but `this` is pointing to your `saveInfo` class which does not have a concept of `email2`. You need to pass in the reference to the fragment's layout by creating a constructor (that's one way to do it).

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I'll add an answer with an example if it helps.

Comment: That would be amazing. Searching SO for fragment constructors isn't going so well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60356/discussion-between-codemonkey-and-jeffk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the edittext values to the AsyncTask as arguments

You should avoid passing views to an asynctask, in case the fragment or activity gets destroyed while an asynctask is still running. It also makes the asynctask more testable by decoupling the logic as much as possible.

```
public void startSaveInfo(){

    String firstEmail = email1.getText().toString();
    String secondEmail = email2.getText().toString();
    String thirdEmail = email3.getText().toString();
    String secaddress = mail1.getText().toString();
    String secaddresstwo = mail2.getText().toString();
    String secCity = cityEt.getText().toString();
    String secState = stateEt.getText().toString();
    String secZip = zipEt.getText().toString();

    new saveInfo().execute(secondemail,thirdEmail,secaddress,secaddresstwo,secCity,secState,secZip)

}

class saveInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            String secondemail = args[0];
            String thirdemail = args[1];
            String secaddress = args[2];
            String secaddresstwo = args[3];
            String secCity = args[4];
            String secState = args[5];
            String secZip = args[6];

            //do your work

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reference `this.email2` etc. in your `saveInfo` class, `this` is a reference to the class which has no concept of the `EditText` objects you have instantiated in your Fragment.

One way of accessing the instance variables is to create a `saveInfo` constructor and sending it your `view` object from the fragment.

In your fragment, or wherever you are calling your saveInfo task:

```
SaveInfo saveInfo = new SaveInfo(view) // 'saveInfo' should be capitalised
```

In `saveInfo`:

```
...
View view;    
public SaveInfo (View view) {
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Check for success tag
    int success;

    try {
        // Building Parameters
        String secondemail = view.email2.getText().toString();
....
```